# Replace a date part with current date -15 days dynamically in multiple files present in a folder

Tags: shell, aix

I am completely newbee to unix.. Can someone help me with a requiement where it is a *(star) delimited file has a multiple lines starts with RTG and 3rd column=TD8 I want to substring the date part and 
I want to replace with currentdate minus 15 days. Here is an example. i am using AIX server

```
$ cat temp.txt  
RTG*888*TD8*20180201~  
TWW*888*RD8*20180301-20180301~  
RTG*888*TD8*20180401-20180501~  
KCG*888*TD8*20180101-20180201~
```

I want the output as below by changing date. Please help. I am looking for UNIX script to make it work for all files present in that directory

```
RTG*888*TD8*20190417~   
TWW*888*RD8*20180201-20180201~  
RTG*888*TD8*20190417-20190417~  
KCG*888*TD8*20180201-20180201~
```

This is working for a single file:

```
awk -v "NewDate=$(TZ=GMT+100 date +%Y%m%d)" '
  BEGIN {
    FS = OFS = "*"
  }
  $1 == "RTG" && $3 == "TD8" {
    gsub(/[0-9]{8}/, NewDate, $4)
  }
  1' file
```

but I want to apply it for all files present in directory.

Comment: `with currentdate minus 15 days` ?? Eh ! the expected output doesn't make much sense

Comment: question posted date(20190502) - 15 days =(20190417) I want to replace with this date

Comment: @oguz ismail, The script you have shared is worked perfectly but I want to apply it for all files present in directory . Kindly help me with modifying the script

Comment: @anil turns out aix doesn't have gnu date, how does it work then?

Comment: @oguz ismail, I did small modification to get the - 15 days and it worked just like that .Kindly help me to modify for all files in directory and write it back to respective files

Comment: @anil edit your question with the working script

Comment: @oguz ismail, Please find the working script for your reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are only dates in fourth column you can replace every group of 8 digits with the new date:

```
awk -v "NewDate=$(date -d '-15 days' +'%Y%m%d')" '
  BEGIN {
    FS = OFS = "*"
  }
  $1 == "RTG" && $3 == "TD8" {
    gsub(/[0-9]{8}/, NewDate, $4)
  }
  1' file
```

Given your sample its output is as follows:

```
RTG*888*TD8*20190418~
TWW*888*RD8*20180301-20180301~
RTG*888*TD8*20190418-20190418~
KCG*888*TD8*20180101-20180201~
```

To apply it to all files in a directory, use a for loop and temporary files:

```
for f in directory/*; do
  awk -v "NewDate=$(date -d '-15 days' +'%Y%m%d')" '
  BEGIN {
    FS = OFS = "*"
  }
  $1 == "RTG" && $3 == "TD8" {
    gsub(/[0-9]{8}/, NewDate, $4)
  }
  1' "$f" > .tmpfile && mv .tmpfile "$f"
done
```

Comment: Error : date: illegal option -- d
Usage: date [-u] [+Field Descriptors] 
I am using AIX

Comment: Aix!date knows less than Gnu!date. Here's a possible replacement: `pldate sub-days 15` source: https://github.com/lzsiga/pldate

Comment: @oguz ismail 
The script provided is working for only one file and just displaying manipulated data content in black screen. How to make it work for all files present in directory and write it back to their respective individual files

Comment: You're awesome man ..its worked as expected .. Thanks a lot for your time and support @oguz ismail